# Choosing Best Average Method-Calculating the average over time

Tags: mean, types-of-averages

Suppose we want to calculate the average annual balance of a customer in the bank.
If we want to have a normal average, we will add up the customer balance in the year and then dividing by the number of days in the year.
Now consider a customer who had a high balance only in the last month of the year and for the last 11 months his account balance has been very low. But because he had a high account balance only in the last month, his annual average shows a high number.
How can we calculate the annual average balance in a way that 11 months of low customer balance affects his annual average and in fact the annual average of the customer does not increase only because of the last month?

Comment: Are you perhaps interested in the median instead of the mean?

Comment: @user2974951 no, median alone can't help .... but maybe we can combine mean and median

Comment: How about... trimean? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimean